# Is there a way to restrict google assistant app only to a certain set of people?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am creating an app using actions-on-google and dialogflow. Is there any way where I can restrict it to only a certain set of people? Others should not be able invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "not really". Think of an Action like a website - anyone with the address can find it and access it.

That said - we have a few approaches that we can use to address this.

First is that, like a website, you can [make sure the user is authorized](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) to access the Action. For users not authorized, you can tell them they're not. In some cases, you might want to tell them how to get added to the authorized list, but that may not be appropriate in your case.

You can also look into the [Alpha / Beta release system](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments). This isn't quite what you're looking for, but you may be able to use it to your advantage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will try the account linking procedure. I am also thinking of creating a database of users and their "secret phrases" (password). The other intents (questions) will be answered only if they pass the first question, answer. Not sure if that'll work, but I am planning to try.